# Игнорировать Where при определенном условии

Tags: c#, linq

Есть функция и linq в ней:

```
public Object Get(string title)
{
   DbSet<Product> p;
   return p.Where(x => x.Title == title).Join(//Далее код)
}
```

Вопрос: как можно игнорировать то что написанно в `Where` при определенном условии (например если `title == null`) и продолжить дальше `Join`???

```
public async Task<Object> Get(string title, string group = null, string category = null)
{
   return _productContext.gropsAndProducts
        .Join(_productContext.groups, gap => gap.GroupId, g => g.Id, (gap, g) =>
        new
        {
            Id = gap.Id,
            ProductId = gap.ProductId,
            GroupTitle = g.Title,
            GroupDiscription = g.Discription,
            CategoryId = g.CategoryId
        })
        .Where(x => x.GroupTitle == group)
        .Join(_productContext.categories, g => g.CategoryId, c => c.Id, (g, c) =>
        new
        {
            Id = g.Id,
            ProductId = g.ProductId,
            GroupTitle = g.GroupTitle,
            GroupDiscription = g.GroupDiscription,
            CategoryId = g.CategoryId,
            CategoryTitle = c.Title,
            CategoryDiscription = c.Discription
        })
        .Where(x => x.CategoryTitle == category)
        .Join(_productContext.product, c => c.ProductId, p => p.Id, (c,p) => 
        new 
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            ProductTitle = p.Title,
            Price = p.Price,
            GroupTitle = c.GroupTitle,
            GroupDiscription = c.GroupDiscription,
            CategoryTitle = c.Title,
            CategoryDiscription = c.Discription
        })
        .Where(x => x.ProductTitle == title)
}
```

Все работает при условие если передаются в функцию не пустые значения

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос. Where применяется к каждому элементу. Вы хотите отметить Where только для какого-то конкретного элемента? Или если найдётся хотя бы один элемент с title == null то отменить Where для всех? И ничего, что у вас в функции p не определён и выдаст NullReferenceException?

Comment: `Where(x => x.Title == title || title == null)` ?

Comment: @AK функция для примера. Вот смотрите: если `title` приходит `null`, то я бы хотел чтобы все было без `where`

Comment: `if (title != null) p = p.where(...)` ?

Comment: @tym32167 `Where(x => x.Title == title || title == null)` не подходит, т к если `title == null` то мне нужно выбрать абсолютно все записи

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц именно это и делает то условие, что вы привели

Comment: Откажитесь от анонимных типов, введя вместо них строгие модели. А дальше, как я показал в ответе: `if` и `IQueryable<точный_тип>`.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо огромное

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov слишком много моделей тогда придется создавать, спасибо за уделенное время

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял:

```
IQueryable<Product> p = db.Products; // DbSet<Product>

if (title != null)
    p = p.Where(x => x.Title == title);

return p.Join(//Далее код);
```

Comment: щас дополню вопрос, в нем не видно нюансов